# Fill missing values in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I would like to get the values in column C

[image]

Column B indicates the changes in the value and I want to create column C based on how the value changes in B

Comment: Do you have `NA` or `""` in column B after you read the data?

Comment: Any reason why column C starts with 20?

Comment: @warmoverflow I have the same questions as you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `na.locf` (assuming that the blanks in 'B' are `NA` after reading the excel file)

```
library(zoo)
df1$C <- na.locf(na.locf(df1$B, na.rm=FALSE), fromLast=TRUE)
df1$C
#[1] 20 20 20 20 30 30 30
```

Data:

```
df1 = structure(list(A = 1:7, B = c(NA, NA, 20, NA, NA, 30, NA)), .Names = c("A", 
"B"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I wanted to use this in conjunction with ave. So just wrapped a function around it and all good! :)